# EXCEL VBA: Append column from one worksheet to the end of another

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the below to copy the first column from sheet 2 to the first column in sheet 1

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
```

However, this overwrites what is there - how would I append the data to what's there already?

Thanks

Comment: Just insert a blank column in sheet1; put this line of code above your line of code `Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Insert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
dim arr as variant, i as long

arr = array("A", "B", "C", "G", "H", "I")

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    for i=lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
        .Range(.Cells(1, arr(i)), .Cells(.Rows.Count, arr(i)).End(xlUp)).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, arr(i)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    next i
End With
```

Comment: Sorted thank you! rather than copying/pasting this code for several columns, is there a quicker way to copy let;s say A, B, C, G, H, I?

Comment: You could loop through an array of column identifiers. See above.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the intersection of the `UsedRange` and `Column(x)`, and pasting to the row below the used range:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(1)).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)
End With
```